# SQL Pivot Dinamico

Tags: sql, pivot

Tengo el siguiente script:

```
Select 
 P.id_persona
,P.nombre
,case when P.cuit IS not null  then P.cuit else P.dni END as 'CUIT'
,TTT.tipo_telefono
,MPT.dato_telefono FROM Persona P
JOIN    Tipo_telefono TT ON P.Tipo_documento  = 1 or P.Tipo_documento = 2
JOIN    Persona_telefono PT ON P.id_persona = PT.id_persona
and PT.Tipo_telefono = TT.Tipo_telefono
```

Y obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
id_persona  Nombre          CUIT        txt_desc            txt_telefono
100         GOOL S.A.       30111111112 RESPONSABLE COBRO   Fabian Banegas
100         GOOL S.A.       30111111112 TEL. RESPONSABLE    5555-4268
100         GOOL S.A.       30111111112 MAIL Gerente        gerente@global.con
100         GOOL S.A.       30111111112 MAIL ENVIO RECIBOS  recibos@global.con
100         GOOL S.A.       30111111112 MAIL ENVIO FACTURAS innvoices@global.con
```

Y necesitaria que el resultado sea el siguiente:

```
id_persona  Nombre      CUIT        RESPONSABLE COBRO   TEL. RESPONSABLE    MAIL Gerente        MAIL ENVIO RECIBOS MAIL ENVIO FACTURAS 
100         GOOL S.A.   30111111112 Fabian Banegas      5555-4268           gerente@global.con  recibos@global.con  innvoices@global.con
```

Mi gran problema es que no logro hacerlo con Pivot ya que por lo que leo, funciona con funciones de agregado.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Se me ocurre que cuando haces el `JOIN` deberias incluir `INNER JOIN`

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos estás utilizando?